# Accessing Vuex action in Javascript ES6 module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, tinymce

I am using NuxtJS framework to build a Vue application. I writing a custom plugin for `TinyMCE` editor to upload images to server. This plugin is an ES6 module with a single export(*I have taken out code for brevity*). So here, image is selected -> compressed -> upload to server.

```
  import { actions } from '@/store/common/post_editor.js'

  const imageUpload = function (editor) {

    function _onAction() {
      let imageBlob = null
       onChange: function (api, details) {
          //get the image selected
          compressImage(image).then((output) => {
          imageBlob = output
        })
      }
    },
    onSubmit: function (api) {
        actions
          .uploadToServer(imageBlob)
          .then((url) => {
            editor.insertContent('<p><img src="' + url + '"/></p>')
          })
          .catch((error) => {
          })
      },
    })
  }
} 

export { imageUpload }
```

I am importing Vuex `action` in the module that uploads the image to server. And following is the code for it.

```
uploadToServer(vuexContext, blob) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('file', blob)
  console.log(this.$axios) // this is undefined
  this.$axios
    .$post('/server/upload', formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      resolve(res.location)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      reject(error)
    })
  })
}
```

But when using this plugin, `axios` is not triggered. And apparently the reason is `this.$axios` is **undefined**. So, it seems this is not the correct way to import Vuex action into an ES6 module.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT**

For now, I am using
`window.$nuxt.context.store .dispatch('common/post_editor/uploadToServer', imageBlob)`

But not sure if this is a good practice.

Comment: You have the access to this.$axios in components. The code that you posted is not a component. You don't need this.$axios at all. Just import it, this is what modules are for

Comment: @EstusFlask `this.$axios` is undefined in Vuex action I am importing. Which otherwise works fine when called from Vue components or other Vuex actions.

Comment: Because `this` needs to be component instance in order to receive plugin properties, and in case of an action it's obviously not.

Comment: @EstusFlask `this` refers to the Store instance.

Comment: That's correct. It's not component instance and isn't expected to have their properties. It's possible there's global $axios https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage/#-shortcuts but I didn't check it and I'd refrain from using it because relying on arbitrary globals in modular environment isn't a good practice either.

Comment: @EstusFlask found a hack to make it work not sure if it is good practice. look at my edit.

Comment: No, it's not a good practice. There's no `window` on server side, for starters. And there are no reasons to use globals if you're able to not use them. The part I didn't mention is that you shouldn't call Vuex actions directly.

Answer (score 0):

Vue and Nuxt plugins define properties on component instances. `this` inside an action is not component instance and so isn't supposed to have `this.$axios`. It's an outdated and questionable practice to use loosely defined `this` dynamic context anywhere besides strict OOP code.

It's incorrect way yo use an action. A store should be imported instead of an action:

```
import store from '.../store`.
```

It's incorrect way to import Axios. It should be explicitly imported in non-component modules. In case there's Axios instance with interceptors, etc, it can be maintained within a module:

```
import axios from '.../common/axios`.
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood. This is not a VueJS plugin but `TinyMCE` plugin which is an ES6 module.

Comment: The answer means Axios Nuxt/Vue plugin when it mentions plugins. That the other thing is TinyMCE plugin doesn't matter. It's just ES module, as you said.

Comment: importing actions from store works. But importing store `import store from '@/store/common/post_editor.js'` gives warning`export 'default' (imported as 'store') was not found in '@/store/common/post_editor.js'`. And that is true `store` is not a default export in store file.

Comment: I'm unaware how modules are structured on your side. You just need to import the store from a module where it's defined. Also another thing that I didn't noticed is that an action is misused. `uploadToServer(vuexContext, blob)` is Vuex action, correct? Actions are supposed to modify the state and not return the result. Otherwise there's no reason to use Vuex global state at all.